# Modifying Output in String Input By Text File (Java)

Tags: java, string, text

thanks to everyone in advance.

I have lines of **strings input through a text file** and would like to modify the output to **remove the last two letters of each string**. This is what the text file currently reads:

> hello how are you 
>   cool
>   i am amazing

and this is the code I'm using (from Java-tips.org)

```
package MyProject

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * This program reads a text file line by line and print to the console. It uses
 * FileOutputStream to read the file.
 * 
 */

public class FileInput {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

File file = new File("MyFile.txt");
FileInputStream fis = null;
BufferedInputStream bis = null;
DataInputStream dis = null;

try {
  fis = new FileInputStream(file);

  // Here BufferedInputStream is added for fast reading.
  bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
  dis = new DataInputStream(bis);

  // dis.available() returns 0 if the file does not have more lines.
  while (dis.available() != 0) {

  // this statement reads the line from the file and print it to
    // the console.
    System.out.println(dis.readLine());
  }

  // dispose all the resources after using them.
  fis.close();
  bis.close();
  dis.close();

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
  }

}
```

The code works perfectly, but I'd like to modify the output to remove the last two letters of each string (string = one per line) Thanks everyone!

Comment: We don't write your programs for you. All you've shown us is that you can read in from the file. Please show some attempt at modifying the Strings in the file.

Comment: I don't understand how you know about `File`, `FileInputStream`, `BufferedInputStream`, `DataInputStream`, etc. but you don't know `String`. As @Tdorno said, you should do more research and try things yourself before asking us to do it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my recommendation. Don't use streams for something so trivial and non-load intensive. Stick to the basics, use a `Scanner` and read your file line-by-line.

Here's the method to success!

1. Learn how to use a [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to read `Strings` from a text file line-by-line.
2. Make sure you split the `Strings` apart with the `str.split()` method accordingly.
3. Store each line's `String` value into a array/list/table.
4. Modify your stored `Strings` to remove the last two letters. Look into the `str.subString(s,f)` method.
5. Learn how to use a [`PrintWriter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html) to output your modified `Strings` to a file.

Good luck!

**Comment Reply**
Read in a line as a `String` from texfile.

```
File file = new File("fileName.txt");
Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
while (input.hasNextLine()) {
   String line = input.nextLine(); //<------This is a String representation of a line 
   System.out.println(line); //prints line
   //Do your splitting here of lines containing more than 1 word
   //Store your Strings here accordingly
   //----> Go on to nextLine
}
```

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson Ahh, good point. One sec!

Comment: Thanks tons! I've been experimenting with scanners and have found this code the easiest to understand although I don't understand how I would "convert" each line into a string. I would know I'd use the following to make modifications:

word = word.substring (0, word.length () - 2); // Removes the last two letters of each word in the first string

but that wouldn't be useful unless I could convert the line into a string :/

Comment: I've figured this out by simply adding: String word = dis.readLine();

Comment: @user3344206 Glad I could help. If your problem has been solved feel free to accept this as an answer.

Comment: lol.  +1 for positive attitude and what seems to be good advice.

Comment: @GeorgeTomlinson What part of point three needs more attention exactly? You simply save the `String` into one of the ten thousand common data structures that exist.

Comment: @ Tdorno Sorry: I'd either forgotten or didn't realise that a whole line could be read into a single string. Thanks for getting back to me!